# Alpine js and Tailwind fetch data

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, alpine.js

I start to learn the alpine js combine with the tailwind. But I don't know how to print the fetch result from json response, try with this

```
<div x-data="orderSearch()"
        class="container mx-auto py-6 px-4"
    >
    <div class="flex border-2 border-gray-200 rounded">
<input type="text" class="px-4 py-2 w-100 uppercase" placeholder="Search" name="orderidSearch"
       x-model="orderidSearch">

<button @click="fetchFulfillment()" class="px-2 py-1 text-white bg-blue-500 rounded hover:bg-green-600">Cari Fulfillment</button>
```

but return the error in console alpine.js:115 Alpine Error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'inv_id')"

Anyone know how to print the result inside div?

My js function:

```
function orderSearch() {
            return {
                orderidSearch: '',
                // other default properties
                
                orders: [],
                fetchOrders() {
                    this.isLoading = true;
                    fetch(`check.php?order_id=${this.orderidSearch}`)
                        .then(res => res.json())
                        .then(data => {
                            this.isLoading = false;
                            this.orders = data.orders;
                            console.log(data);
                        });
                    console.log(this.orders);

                },
                ....
```

json return data:

```
{"data":[{"inv_id":"8768768768"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you will get an iterable object. I rewrite your code a little bit and put the function inline to show the first entry. If you have a collection then build your loop to sow every item.

```html
<div 
   class="container mx-auto py-6 px-4"
   x-data="{
    orders: null,
    isLoading: false,
    orderSearch() {
        this.isLoading = true;
        fetch(`check.php?order_id=${this.orderidSearch}`)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => this.orders = json);
    }
}" x-init="orderSearch()">
    <p x-text="orders[0].inv_id"></p>    
</div>
```

Comment: Tried this, but return the error: Alpine Error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"

Comment: @Bekka The problem is that i dont know your entire code and what your api returns. You must adapting first because you know what the api returns. But maybe i can help you to point you in the right direction if you share the current error.

Comment: I updated the question, the fetch api trigger if button hit

Comment: @Bekka Your button trigger `fetchFulfillment()` method and not the `orderSearch()` Method.

Comment: Thanks, that's my fault. this works now. I started with your sample script and adapt to my existing.